# How can i Improve this database , and the relations between the tables is it fine?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

[image: Database Schema]

I will use this database to build a website using Laravel Framework.

Comment: You would be better served by posting a DBfiddle of it with some sample data.  https://www.db-fiddle.com  Just looking in it you have some redundant data, the database's main goal is normalizing data, so if you have a one to one, than you don't really need a separate table for it (unless you need separate engines for them, like InnoDB and MyIsam), (like delivery address).  Then status could be an ENUM field how many status will you have and how often will they change.  They will probably never change and you probably will only have 4 or 5 of them.

Comment: There is a problem with such questions: Without context, it is hard to give advice if something makes sense or not. At least if your question is not only about whether you adhered to the normal form or not. What could be an improvement, depending on your desired business logic, is to make payment details a permanent thing a user can store for later usage. Also the category system feels a bit weird, you should probably use a recursive table for that (which gives you more flexibility with depth of your sub-categories). But as stated, it is hard to give advice without context.

Comment: I don't like category systems, I prefer using a tagging system.  For one thing it's flat, for anther you can have unlimited tags.  Also I agree the payment details need some work, there is no relation between `payment_details` and `user_payment_details`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix
thank you for Answering

i tried to use DBfiddle ([www.db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) ) but i got a lot of errors , because i used dbdesigner ( [dbdesigner.net](http://dbdesigner.net) ) just to design the database, i am not working on the queries right now.

i know there is a lot of one to one relationships in the database , i am using that tables to populate the select tag in the forms when i create the web pages

Comment: Have you created the tables, you can do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and the result will be sql to create the table.  In PHPmyAdmin you have to click "show full texts" to see the whole thing.

Comment: no i did not create the tables yet , as i told you i am working on the design of the tables and the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned this is too broad to answer.

But I can give you some pointers to remember.

**Normalization**

This is the primary purpose of relationships.  Basically this is not duplicating data, so you wouldn't put a state in every address you would have a state table and put it's id in the address.

You have some of this, but you can over normalize too. Like the payment status. Likely these wont change much over time so you could use an ENUM field which is basically a text field with a list of acceptable values in it.

Pretty much if you have a One to One relationship, you don't really need another table for it.  The only reason I can think of was back when InnoDB didn't have full text support, then you could make a MyIsam table and a InnoDB table to kind of use both their benefits.  Otherwise it just makes things harder because you have an extra join, and you have to make user that you tables dont become a Many to One relationship.

An example in yours is Orders and Delivery Addresses, this would probably be a one to one, it's not like you can deliver the same item to more then one address.  Your probably thinking, I can reuse those addresses for different orders, but if you read below you might see why that is not always a good idea.  Which is not saying you cant use them again, you just probably shouldn't allow edits to them and that can cause a whole cascade of issues.

**Consistancy**

When dealing with things like orders, you should bake as much data into the table as you can. This is de-normalization.  But the reason is that, products can be deleted addresses can change etc.  You don't want these things affecting your orders later.  So by baking that data in you don't have to worry about not being able to change those things.  Obviously you still want some links like to the User but you may want to bake in the email they used for that order, that way latter if they say I didn't get the email, you can know what email was used not the one they currently have, maybe they changed it.

**Hierarchies**

This is specifically for the category table, you may want to look at some of the hierarchy models like nested set, or adjacency list.  This will eliminate tables and allow more nesting levels.  It's quite a bit harder to setup, but it's way more flexible.

Another choice is to use something like a tag system, where you have a list of tags and associate those with the products through a many to many relationship.  I think we all know what tags are but if your not sure, than look at the tags on Stack Overflow.  These can help improve search results and help tie related products together even if they are in different categories.  For example you could have

```
veggies > potatoes

utensils > potato peelers
```

They are related, but you probably won't put them in the same category.

You could even use both!

Comment: Thanks this is really Useful. although, i did not understand how to bake data, if you can give me an example how to bake date from table to table i will be thankful, and about the Hierarchies for products categories will be like this
Product has type, type has sub-category, sub-category has category example:
product  -> oxford -> shoe -> apparel, if i am doing it wrong please guide me.

Comment: All I mean by `bake data` is you put the data in the table instead of reference it with an id, it's baked in it wont change etc. etc.  ` please guide me` this is site is about specific programing issues, this is why questions like this is discouraged, there are plenty of tutorials and videos that can do a much better job then i can to explain it.

Comment: ok understood , thank you.

Answer (score 2):

from my experience, when you are developing an online store, the information about orders should be stored separately, not with relations
let me give you an example:

i order product A, my order is being processed, meanwhile, you delete product A from your database (different reasons), if you have the product_id in my order, what will happen?.

Also, you should make an intersection table for users and payment details, they may have more credit cards. An intersection table for users and delivery addresses would also be easier to manage than a text colum

Comment: I would add it should be "baked" into the order, that way if you change a product later it has no effect on billing, you could delete a product and break all your orders, if you require they have a relationship.